# Is there a rest api method for getting an Docusign OAuth Token that works?

Tags: docusignapi

I have been using the https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi site to look through available methods but when I have tried to use the getOAuthToken method under authentication to work, it gives me a 400 error every time I try to use it. Is there another method that works for this?

Comment: what parameters have you passed to method?
did you create a developer account?
did you create an integration key?
are you using JWT or Auth Code Grant for authenticaiton?

Comment: is this method on one of the SDKs/Client library? what lang? can you share the full code you run?

Comment: the method I am using is the one located at https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi?categories=Authentication&tags=Authentication&operations=getOAuthToken, it asks for no parameters. I have a developer account, I am not running this in an app at the moment, I just want to see if I can get the rest request to work in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API Explorer refers to a deprecated form of the OAuth workflow.

The more up-to-date version is available here: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant

Code examples are available in the DocuSign Github in various languages: https://github.com/docusign?q=auth-code-grant&type=&language=

Comment: Ah I understand, I had looked in the different Oauth methods on that page briefly but felt that they might be more than what I would require so I had just been looking for a smaller set up. Thank you for the help!